# JMeter 5.2 - Import from cUrl checkbox

Tags: jmeter

I download JMeter 5.2 and tried the Tools -> Import from cUrl

I tried with different URLs e.g. `curl https://www.keycdn.com`

But there's a checkbox `Add cookie header to Cookie Manager` which I don't understand

If it checked or not, the results are the same ( only order of components are flipped)

What is the use case for checkbox? is it relevant? example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more than relevant given your request contains [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header and you're sending only [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent).

[image]

References:

- [curl - Set Cookies](https://catonmat.net/cookbooks/curl/set-cookies)
- [HTTP cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies)
- [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide/)

Comment: It expects argument-value parameter, i.e. `curl -b "JSESSIONID=foo" http://example.com`